# WAMP does not open my project

Tags: php, git, localhost, wamp

I am completely new to web-dev and wamp, I have to use it for a college project to build a website using php. I installed the newest version of wamp. I cloned my project repository into the www folder.

When I run "localhost" in the browser, I get the generic wamp page and I can see my project folder  on the bottom of the page under the "Projects" heading

when I click on the project it does not open and I get a 404 not found error. This is not the same issue a thousands other people have written about, where when they uses the path "localhost/projectname" they get access to their project but when they just click their project the path is "projectname" and they dont see their project. I have read tons of posts with people that have that problem and I do not think I have the same issue becase when I click on my project link on the wamp hompage, I get the complete path "http://localhost/PaperCloudBackend/" and this shows a 404  error

Keep in mind that all I have done with wamp so far is:
1) install it
2) clone repo into www folder
3) opened browser with localhost
4) clicked on my project name

I would really like a concise answer to why this is happening so I can learn the root cause, and also a solution to the problem because i have not contributed to my team codebase at all and I have not been able to solve this issue after 1 week.

Thanks

Comment: I think this post will help explain why and what to do about it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665064/project-links-do-not-work-on-wamp-server/23990618#23990618

Answer (score 1):

I assume that its an .htaccess error which is clashing . If you have .htaccess in your project then check it if you have given the correct url in the .htaccess rule or you can delete the file(.htaccess) and run the project in your browser.
Another problem that you should check is there any index file is present in the root of the folder you are trying to access.
I hope this might help you.

Comment: Our project is using Slim (no idea exactly what this does yet) but i deleted the .htaccess file there, still getting the same error. Thanks for that insight though, it was a good call. The index.php file is definately present in my root file, i even try to add it to my address bar and run it directly but to no avail

Comment: Since your using slim create the .htaccess file in the root of your project and put this below code/rule in it and try to run

`#ErrorLog "logs/mysite.com-error.log"
#CustomLog "logs/mysite.com-access.log" combined

<Directory "/path/www.mysite.com/public_html">
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>`

as well as you have to also midified your apache server to allow .htaccess file follow the below path and instruction

` /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf and changed:

AllowOverRide None

to

AllowOverride All`
i hope this will help you to solve your problem

Comment: Hi, I copied the index.php file into the root www folder. I renamed it pp.php since there is already a wamp "index.php" file in the www directory. Now when I insert "localhost/pp.php" I get the same error. Given this new data, do you think that the solution you suggested is still the correct one? Thank you also for your continued help.

Comment: I will suggest you to create a folder in your www folder and copy your entire repo in it and change the pp.php back to index.php and also create the .htaccess in the root of your repo directory and add the above .htaccess rule . this might sove your problem

Comment: can you clarify the above htaccess command, its unlear what is a comment and what is actual code. Thanks again

Comment: line starting with the # is comment your .htaccess file will look like this

`#ErrorLog "logs/mysite.com-error.log" \n

#CustomLog "logs/mysite.com-access.log" combined\n

 <Directory "/path/www.mysite.com/public_html">\n

 AllowOverride All \n

Order allow,deny Allow from all \n

</Directory>`\n

\n define new line don't put the \n in your .htaccess file just replace the \n with new line or press line break

Comment: The new lines help, thank you. PS I know not to put the new line char in the htaccess file haha.

Comment: if it helps then please up vote my answer . Thank you @ Milad

Answer (score 1):

Currently thats also happed with me on window8.1, To prevent this open the index.php file from root directory `wamp/www/index.php.`

Change

```
$suppress_localhost = true;
```

To

```
$suppress_localhost = false;
```

Hope this will help you to fix the problem.

Comment: Hi, it was originally set to false, I changed it to true, the only thing this did was add the localhost\in the beginning of the path which logically helps because with that line set to false, when I click my project link on the wamp homepage, it will input my project name in all lowercase letter in the address bar and I get a dns look up error. What I am saying is that with $suppress_localhost = true; I think it makes more sense but either way, changing that option did not help me :(

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that index file exist in your "PaperCloudBackend" directory as it is the entry point of execution.

Comment: index.php file exists.